# DynamoDb check that a SS attribute in contained in a given SS

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Lets say I have this schema:

```
source_id              -> String, HashKey
created_at             -> String, RangeKey
required_capabilities  -> StringSet
```

required_capabilities is a Set of Strings that we need to provide in the query in order to be able to retrieve a particular element.

For example:
If I have this three elements:

```
{
  "source_id": "1",
  "created_at": "2021-01-18T10:53:25Z",
  "required_capabilities": ["Cap1", "Cap2", "Cap3"]
},
{
  "source_id": "1",
  "created_at": "2021-01-18T10:59:31Z",
  "required_capabilities": ["Cap1", "Cap3"]
},
{
  "source_id": "1",
  "created_at": "2021-01-18T11:05:15Z"
}
```

I want to create a query, filtering for example source_id = "1" and providing a FilterExpression with the `required_capabilities = ["Cap1", "Cap3", "Cap4"]`.

And I would expect as a result:

```
{
  "source_id": "1",
  "created_at": "2021-01-18T10:59:31Z",
  "required_capabilities": ["Cap1", "Cap3"] // Since I've provided "Cap1", "Cap3" and "Cap4"
},
{
  "source_id": "1",
  "created_at": "2021-01-18T11:05:15Z" // Since it doesn't require any capability.
}
```

I've tried the IN operator as follows, since the stored StringSet should be IN (or Contained by)  the given SS, but it didn't work.

`aws dynamodb query --table-name TableName --key-condition-expression "source_id = :id" --filter-expression "required_capabilities IN (:rq)"  --expression-attribute-values '{":id": {"S": "1"}, ":rq": { "SS": ["Cap1", "Cap3", "Cap4"] }}'`

It works only when I provide the exact same StringSet, but If I provide a set that contains the saved one and also have more values, it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found out that dynamodb doesn't support the use case I needed, so I found a workaround.

Basically instead of modelling the `required_capabilities` as a StringSet, I've created a field called `required_capability`, containing a single required capability (which is ok so far for me) and using the `IN` operator to check.

If in the future I need to check for more than one capability, I just need to add new fields `required_capability_2` and `required_capability_3`.

It's clearly not ideal, but I guess it's good enough, considering I won't have a lot of required capabilities in a single record, it's usually one, maybe two.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your issue is around the use of the `IN` keyword, which does not work with sets. From [the docs on conditionals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html)

> IN : Checks for matching elements in a list.
> AttributeValueList can contain one or more AttributeValue elements of type **String, Number, or Binary**. These attributes are compared against an existing attribute of an item. If any elements of the input are equal to the item attribute, the expression evaluates to true.

I believe you want the `CONTAINS` keyword:

> CONTAINS : Checks for a subsequence, or value **in a set**.
> AttributeValueList can contain only one AttributeValue element of type String, Number, or Binary (not a set type). If the target attribute of the comparison is of type String, then the operator checks for a substring match. If the target attribute of the comparison is of type Binary, then the operator looks for a subsequence of the target that matches the input. If the target attribute of the comparison is a set ("SS", "NS", or "BS"), then the operator evaluates to true if it finds an exact match with any member of the set. CONTAINS is supported for lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a" can be a list; however, "b" cannot be a set, a map, or a list.

Comment: The problem is that CONTAINS checks that the given set CONTAINS the stored one. I need the other way around.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!